# How to put an image between two UL with absolute positioning?

Tags: css, position, css-position, fixed

In my header I have a logo with an image sprite on both sides of the image. I am trying to center them horizontally to the top of the browser. The header has to be positioned:fixed.

HTML:

```
<div id="headerbg">             
            <div id="header">
                <ul id="navleft">   
                    <li id="navhome"><a href="#top"></a></li>
                    <li id="navnew"><a href="#new"></a></li>
                    <li id="navbrands"><a href="#brands"></a></li>
                </ul>               
                <div id="logo"></div>
                <ul id="navright">  
                    <li id="navsales"><a href="#sales"></a></li>
                    <li id="navlocation"><a href="#location"></a></li>
                    <li id="navcontact"><a href="#contact"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>          
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#headerbg
{
background-color: #ffffff;
width:100%;
height:50px;    
z-index: 1000;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left:0;
}

#header
{   
width: 800px;
height: 100px;
margin: auto;
}

#logo
{
width:200px;
height:100px;
background:url(images/logo_small.jpg);
display:inline-block;
z-index: 2000;      
}

/* NAVIGATION */

#navleft
{
position:relative;

}

#navleft li
{
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
position:absolute;
top:0;
z-index: 2000;
}

#navleft li, #navleft a
{
height:50px;
display:block;
}

#navright
{
position:relative;

}

#navright li
{
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
position:absolute;
top:0;
z-index: 2000;
}

#navright li, #navright a
{
height:50px;
display:block;
}
```

I left out CSS for the hover images of the sprite to shorten my post. I appreciate any help I can get. Thanks!

Comment: I find its still unclear what you try to do. The solution may be really simple. Would you have a link to the page you try this code on. ... "image sprite on both sides of the image"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already know the width of the header and the logo. You then knnow that each `ul` should have a `width: 300px;` and just set them all to `float:left;` or `display:inline;`

```
#header ul {
    width:300px;
}

#header {
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; /* IE hack */
}
```

**EDIT**

You could also apply specific CSS styles for psuedo element e.g.:

```
#header ul:first-child {
    width:300px;
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

#header ul:last-child {
    width:300px;
    position:relative;
    right:0;
    left:0;
}
```

I have retyped your code to fit your needds (well what I assume is your needs)

see fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/aLQYS/

And for the future, I will recommend you to use classes instead of Id's. Not only you save the  ID tag for something more important such as javascript, but you  also have the possibility of reusing your css styles by adding multiple classes to one object e.g.

**CSS**

```
.shadow {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.box {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="shadow box"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. everything looks good except #navright is showing up outside of the header div for some reason. HTML looks good to me. I copy and pasted straight from jsfiddle

Comment: according to the `#navright` there might be some other CSS in your code that conflicts with what I have been writtn.. A good tool to live manipulate with css would be Google Chrome Developer tools. If you are previewing the page in Google Chrome, you can right click on an element and picking `control element` and then you will be able to manipulate the css live. This will not affect the original script so you have to copy the CSS into your script afterwords.